# Display Date from calendar list in Content editor

Tags: sharepoint-server, calendar, script, date, script-webpart

I have a calendar list that displays outages of various products.
ex.
Product 1. | 1st Jan. | server down
Product 2. | 1st Jan  | server down
Product 3. | 5th Jan. | maintenance

On top of this list there is a content editor web part.
In this web part I need to display the difference of today's date and the date on which latest outage occurred. Basically Today's Date minus Creation Date of the latest item in the list.

Can someone please help me with the content editor script ?

Thanks a lot to all of you!

Regards,
SVG

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below script to achieve this:

```
<div> The difference of today's date and the date on which latest outage occurred is:</div>
<div id="myDiv"></div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script>
var items;
$(function(){
  var caml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EndDate' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>";
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
  var web = ctx.get_web();
  //change to your calendar name
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("calendar");
  var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
  query.set_viewXml(caml);
  items = list.getItems(query);
  ctx.load(items)
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(onsuccess, onfailed); 
});
function onsuccess() {
    var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    enumerator.moveNext();
    var item = enumerator.get_current();
    var id = item.get_id();
    var today=new Date();
    var date=item.get_item('EndDate');
    var diff=Math.floor((Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()) - Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()) ) /(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));     
    $('#myDiv').html(diff);      
    }
 
function onfailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above solution; really appreciate it!!!

Comment: 1) If the latest incident was added today; it gives the difference as " -1".
2) I actually have a main calendar  named "Calendar" which contains list of multiple products. I have created filtered lists off of the main calendar list which contains outages for specific products: "Calendar list 1", "Calendar list 2", etc. When I place the content editor and above script over the main calendar and reference in the script as "Calendar" it works fine. Though when I keep the script in content editor and above individual list and reference i the script as "Calendar list 1" - it does not work.